# Django won't create a table

Tags: django, postgresql, migration

I have two different databases in django. Initially, I had a table called cdr in my secondary database. I decided to get rid of the second database and just add the cdr table to the first database.

I deleted references (all of them, I think) to the secondary database in the settings file and throughout my app. I deleted all of the migration files and ran make migrations fresh.

The table that used to be in the secondary database is not created when I run migrate even though it doesn't exist on my postgres database.

I simply cannot for the life of me understand why the makemigrations function will create the migration file for the table when I add it back in to the model definition and I have verified that it is in the migration file. When I run migrate, it tells me there are no migrations to apply.

Why is this so. I have confirmed that I have managed=True. I have confirmed that the model is not on my postgres database by logging into the first database and running \dt.

Why does Django still think that this table still exists such that it is telling me no migrations to apply even though it shows a create command in the migrations file? I even dropped the secondary database to make sure it wasn't somehow being referenced.

I suspect code isn't needed to explain this to me but I will post if needed. I figure I am missing something simple here.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does Django still think that this database still exists such that
>   it is telling me no migrations to apply even though it shows a create
>   command in the migrations file

Because django maintains a table called django_migrations in your database which lists all the migrations that have been applied. Since you are almost starting afresh, clear out this table and then run the migrations.

If this still doesn't work and still assuming that you are still on a fresh start, it's a simple matter to drop all the tables (or even the database and do the migration again). OTH that you have data you want to save, you need to look at the --fake and --fake-initial options to migrate

Comment: Thank you. When I attempt to clean this table I run into a slew of new problems. content types as permission table issues arise. I clean the relevant records from those tables and then I haver errors with either it saying a column already exists on a table or that a column does not exist on a table. Thankfully this is all done on a test server, but is there a better strategy to solve this problem on my live server?

Comment: Could you also tell me why I got a negative one for my question? I researched answers on Stack, I read the documentation and I attempted solutions on my own for several hours. As well, I posted the most thorough description I could. I would like to do better, please advice the problem with my post.

Comment: no idea, the down vote didn't come from me. I am guessing that probably because there are lots of migration related questions here someone thought it was duplicate but was too lazy to tag as duplicate.

Comment: so how did this go in the end?